# Draw Sprite On Pixel Color

Tags: c#, colors, xna, sprite, pixel

I've done a small game with a simple tile engine that draws a sprite corresponding to a number in a .txt file. And now I want to advance, I want to make so the game reads a .png or something and for every pixel it draws a sprite. And with different colors within the image, a different sprite draws. Can some one help me with this? Also, I'm doing this in C# XNA 4.0.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. How can you draw a sprite in a .txt file? Also, it is impossible to draw a sprite on a pixel, as a pixel could be represented as a 1x1 sprite.

Comment: I mean that you load a texture into the game and on every pixel on the texture, the game draws a sprite. So the texture becomes like a map, or something like that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Texture2D.GetData` can be tricky if your using it to make a tile map (Im assuming a map would be a 2D grid of tiles) because Texture2D.[GetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197093.aspx) returns a 1D array.

First of all you will need your array for the map, However you store it it may look like this:

```
Color[,] tiles = new Color[LEVEL_WIDTH,LEVEL_HEIGHT];
```

I used the following technique for loading premade structures from files

```
//Load the texture from the content pipeline
Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Your Texture Name and Directory");

//Convert the 1D array, to a 2D array for accessing data easily (Much easier to do Colors[x,y] than Colors[i],because it specifies an easy to read pixel)
Color[,] Colors = TextureTo2DArray(texture);
```

And the function...

```
    Color[,] TextureTo2DArray(Texture2D texture)
    {
        Color[] colors1D = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height]; //The hard to read,1D array
        texture.GetData(colors1D); //Get the colors and add them to the array

        Color[,] colors2D = new Color[texture.Width, texture.Height]; //The new, easy to read 2D array
        for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++) //Convert!
            for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
                colors2D[x, y] = colors1D[x + y * texture.Width];

        return colors2D; //Done!
    }
```

Now you may want to set your map, to the colors, So simply do `tiles = Colors`, and you could easily access data from the array with `Colors[x,y]`!

Example:

```
 using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    class Game
    {
        //"Global" array for the map, this holds each tile
        Color[,] tiles = new Color[LEVEL_WIDTH, LEVEL_HEIGHT];
        protected override void Initialize() //OR wherever you load the map and stuff
        {
            //Load the texture from the content pipeline
            Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Your Texture Name and Directory");

            //Convert the 1D array, to a 2D array for accessing data easily (Much easier to do Colors[x,y] than Colors[i],because it specifies an easy to read pixel)
            Color[,] Colors = TextureTo2DArray(texture);
        }
        Color[,] TextureTo2DArray(Texture2D texture)
        { //ADD THE REST, I REMOVED TO SAVE SPACE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this seams like a good answer but I'm kinda new to C# XNA, and I don't know were to put this in my code and how I'm suppose to use it. Would you be a gent and simplify this ? If you want.

Comment: You may see other methods, such as Draw(GameTime gameTime), Update(), etc. Add TextureTo2DArray(Texture2D texture) method, in the same area those are. Where do you load a map? Where ever that is add the first code.

Comment: I feel so stupid now, I still don't get how I'm suppose to do to make it draw a sprite from my spritesheet on the pixel. One sprite is 32x32. And if I make a map I'll have a for example 64x64 .png and on every pixel it draws a sprite, so if you just paint a row of pixel on top of the picture. So in-game it will be 64 rows of the sprite I set. So 64(32x32). Sorry for the stupidness.

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x < LEVEL_WIDTH; x++) {                             for (int y = 0; y < LEVEL_HEIGHT; y++) {              spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, new Vector2(x * 32, y*32))                   }}` That will loop through every tile, and draw it at x,y * 32. Why times 32? Because we need to offset it by 32 (sprite size) for each tile.

Comment: I meant on tile should be 32x32 in pixels.

Comment: 32x32 per tile in a spritesheet that's 128x128.

Comment: Where do I define what sprite goes on what color?

Comment: `Color[,] Colors = TextureTo2DArray(texture); ` "Colors" is the array you have for the sprites

Comment: I don't really get it,e.g how do I assign the color red to paint the second tile in my tilesheet?

Comment: during the spriteBatch.Draw I posted above, do something like `if (colors[x,y] ==  Color.Red) {spriteBatch.Draw(2ND SPRITE, new Vector2(x * 32, y*32)) }` If you are using a tile sheet, you must define a rectangle to draw it from. That is a tottally different matter and needs to be asked in a seperate question!

Comment: Where is the color stored? For example I need to check the pixel on (320, 240). Where is it stored ?

Comment: Color[,] Colors = TextureTo2DArray(texture); When you call that to get your texture array, then do Colors[320,240]. I would advise I brush up on the basics of C# and XNA

Comment: I tryed that and it didn't work, therefor I asked. But I assume I did something wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

first, use the pipleine to load the image in to a Texture2D.  then in your code use texture2d.GetData to get the colour of the pixel.

MSDN texture2d.GetData Example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197093.aspx